# mermaidのフローチャートRLでsubgraphの配置を上下から左右に変えたい

Tags: mermaid

mermaidでフローチャートをRLに指定して書いておりますが、下記図のように
BeforeとRebasedのsubgraphを上下ではなく、左右に並べることはできないでしょうか?
エディタはTyporaを使っております。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
graph RL
subgraph 4_[Rebased]
    1_[commit 1]
    2_[commit 2]
    3_[commit 3]
    2_ --> 1_
    3_ --> 2_

    subgraph master-
    2_
    end
    subgraph feature-
    3_
    end
end
style 4_ fill:#fdc
subgraph 4[Before]
    1[commit 1]
    2[commit 2]
    3[commit 3]
    2 --> 1
    3 --> 1
    subgraph master
    2
    end
    subgraph feature
    3
    end
end
style 4 fill:#fdc
classDef red fill:#F77
class 3_,3 red
```

以上、何卒ご教授宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 念のため、mermaid はテキストベースで記述できる点が「Markdown に似てる」であり、記法そのものは Markdown とは異なります。

Comment: @cubick 様　Markdownファイルの中にmermaidのコマンドを挿入してフローチャートを描いていたので勘違いしておりました。ご指摘頂きありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

`graph RL`による図形の配置を維持したままで左右に並べる回答ではありません。
単に左右に並べるだけなら、以下のとおり、graphのRLをTBに変えればよいと思います。

```
graph TB
```

`VScode`の`Markdown Preview Mermaid Support`での結果は以下のとおりです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

推測ですが、`mermaid`の`graph`は`graphviz`の`rankdir`に対応していると思います。

```
rankdir

TB : top to bottom.
BT : bottom to top.
LR : left to right.
RL : right to left.
```

---

邪道ですが、見えないリンクを引く方法があります。
次の2行を追加するとRebasedとBeforeが並んで表示されます。

[image: 例]

```
1_ --- 2
linkStyle 4 stroke-width:0px
```

Comment: 早速ご回答頂き、誠にありがとうございます。説明不足で申し訳ございませんが、今回は図形の配置を変えないでRLのままできればと考えておりました。見えないリンクを引く方法は全く思いつきませんでしたが、これならRLのまま左右に並べることが出来ますね。大変助かりました。重ねて御礼申しあげます。